# Possible to create validating constraints / primary keys without indexes?

Tags: oracle, indexing, constraints

I'm working a data migration project, where some tables will only be loaded once. 
I.e. a table will be fully loaded using only one Select From Insert Into.

I want to assure data integrity with the usage of primary keys and constraints.

With Oracle, when ever I create a primary key or constraint Oracle will automatically create the corresponding index for me.

Is it possible to disable the creation of the index? Note that I still want the constraint to be validated as needed ... so that in the off chance that Oracle actually needs to do a validation it will either create the index (on an as needed basis) .. or do a Full Table Scan.

The reason that I want to disable or defer this index creation, is that I noticed that most of the indexes (for constraints) that get created don't actually get used. I do this by turning on Usage Monitoring for all indexes, running the data migration process, and then verifying v$object_usage.

Comment: My 2 cents: The idea of constraints is that they are checked. And to check a constraint you really want to use an index. So either don't create a constraint (check it manually, or use a db trigger), or accept the creation of an index.

Comment: I think in my case it's not really being checked (at least it's not using the index). I'm guessing what's happening is that when I do the insert Oracle is skipping constraint checking as I'm loading Foreign Keys directly from the corresponding tables (so in that case there is no need to actually do a constraint check as Oracle knows that the match record actually exists).

Comment: Fortunately Oracle will not allow you (or anyone else) do such a mistake.

Comment: Usage monitoring only checks if an index is used during a query to fetch data; it doesn't cover index usage when used to validate unique, primary key, or foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle uses a unique index to enforce a primary key constraint. You can't create a primary key without the corresponding index being created unless you create it in the disabled state, in which case you don't get your primary key enforcement unless and until you enable it.

EDIT:

If there is an index that Oracle can use already on the column(s) used in a primary key, then Oracle will use that index to enforce the constraint, unique or not. If Oracle must create the index, it will be unique, unless the constraint is deferrable in which case it will be nonunique. Thanks to Shannon and Adam for comments.

Comment: A clarification: Oracle needs an index to enforce a primary key or unique constraint. It does not need to be a unique index. Also, Oracle will not create the index, if there is an existing one it can use.

Comment: The `USING INDEX [myschema.myindex]` clause tells Oracle which index to create or hijack. If myschema.myindex is specified, Oracle will attempt to use it to enforce the index, otherwise Oracle will create that a unique index with the contstraint's name and column definition.

Comment: Oracle will create an if no usable index already exists on the column. It will create a unique index if the constraint is not deferrable. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** The bit answering the question in this answer is wrong.

<s>**DISCLAIMER:** I don't believe this is wise</s>

It's possible to replicate the actions of a `primary key constraint` without actually creating a primary key. This is because the *constraint*, non-index, part of a PK constraint is effectively a combination of a `not null constraint` and a `unique constraint`, which *are* stackable. You then don't have an index. So, yes. It's possible.

But:

1. The idea of a table where the PK is **never** used seems unlikely.
2. Having just had to solve the problems created when someone decided that being overly fancy with PKs was a good idea about 10 years ago.

I would highly recommend you go down the normal route and create a primary key. Space is cheap and you'll probably regret it later if you don't.

Comment: A unique constraint will also result in an index, unless an existing index can be used.

Comment: Ach @ShannonSeverance, you're right; I never knew that; then again never added one without using an index... For anyone making similar stupid mistakes here's a useful [AskTom link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:8188769874548604::::P11_QUESTION_ID:36858373078604).

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty set on Referential Integrity ... and I certainly wouldn't remove the contraints .. But through analysis I can see that a lot of indexes aren't actually being used for constraint checking. Eliminating the indexes in my case would produce a substantial performance improvement.